# go get: disabled by -mod=vendor

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using Go modules, and I use vendoring mode, as it speed up 2x my CI.

I do:

```
go mod vendor
go build -mod=vendor ...
```

and I can build my app without any issue.

But when I want to use `go get`, for instance to install `golint`:

```
go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint
```

It will download all my project dependencies again, not just golint.

If I try:

```
go get -mod=vendor -u golang.org/x/lint/golint
```

I get:

```
go get: disabled by -mod=vendor
```

Lint will be used in my dev docker image, but not in the prod one, so I don't want to add it to `go.mod`

What can I do about it ?

Comment: Why would your prod docker image contain any source code at all?

Comment: it's not, but I guess binary is going to be bigger if there is more dependencies isn't it ?

Comment: No. The binary only includes packages imported (directly or transitively) from `main`.

Comment: Ok, wonderful, so I can include all my test dependencies, etc. at no cost. Problem solved. I will even save a docker layer

Comment: @Adrian it is ok, but I can't find my binary... Do you know where it is ? I tried  $GOPATH/bin/golint but it is not here :(

Comment: You did not tell after which exactly actions you failed to find the binary. All in all, adding the `-x` command-line flag to any `go` call which is supposed to compile comething usually makes that tool be explicit about what it's doing; try that.

Answer (score 0):

`go get` maintains consistency among your dependencies' requirements, and uses the graph of `import` statements in source files to determine which packages to update.

So `go get -u` necessarily must download at least the `go.mod` files for your dependencies, plus the source code for the requested package and *its* upgraded dependencies.